# Angular read more button based on NUMBER OF LINES not number of letters

Tags: css, angularjs, ellipsis

What I need is an Angular or CSS solution which will add a "read more" button if the text is more than 5 lines long.

I have an Angular page which displays text, which has a letter limit of 150 characters.

> {{post.post_text | limitTo:letterLimit}}

But in some instances the posts are too long, because they have been written with many many line breaks ie :

- my post
- line 2
- line 3
- l
- i
- n
- e

...still less than 150 chars, but it begins to break my page.

So I need is an Angular or CSS solution which will add a "read more" button if the text is more than 5 lines long.

Forgive me, but this is my first attempt at Angular, I don't know where to start! Any help would be much appreciated.

> so far

I have only found answers and tutorials which relate to number of characters. I really need a solution based on number of lines or total line-height. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try such a filter:

```
{{post.post_text | limitTo:letterLimit | maxLines: linesLimit}} // toggle lines limit with the show more

app.filter('maxLines', function() {
    return function(txt,  limit) {

        var parts = txt.split("\n");

        if(limit == 0) return parts.join('<br/>');
        return parts.slice(0,limit).join('<br/>');
    }
})
```

In view:

```
<button class="show-more" ng-if="checkLines(checkLines(resource.description)"></button>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.lines_limit_default = 3;// ex.

function checkLines(txt) {
  if(txt && txt != null) {   
    return (txt.split("\n").length > $scope.lines_limit_default) ? true : false;
  } else return false;
};
```

Comment: Great! Thats almost got it. I need to swap the '<br/>'s for '\n's as the returned result is a string, not HTML.

Comment: there is one thing i'm still stuck with. How to not show the button if this linesLimit is not reached?

Comment: I use this function:      function checkLines(txt) {
      if(txt && txt != null) {   
        return (txt.split("\n").length > vm.lines_limit_default) ? true : false;
      } else return false;
    }; // vm is the $scope and lineslimit_default is set by you as desired, perform the check on the read more button

Comment: The checkLines function doesn't work. In fact it prevents the Show More button working. No Error in console, it just never returns true. Do you think you could get it working in JSfiddle?